# How to implement a json parser here?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I created a post request with json and it works pretty well. But now I want to insert the output of this json post request into my database.

So I need to create a json parser to seperate the string like this: "Bestellnummer:1", "Besteller:8195529", "Zeit: 2019-09-27 15:50:07", "Artikelnummer:76194", "Anzahl:1", "Preis:2.968"... (next Artikelnummer and so on...).

Bestellnummer = orderid, Besteller = customerid, Zeit = time, Artikelnummer=articleid, Anzahl = number of article, Preis= price

I tried to do something like a parser in my code, but I never did something like this befor and unfortuntly don't know how to involve this parser in my code.

I hope u can help me

One example for my json Output:

```
{"Bestellnummer":"1","Besteller":"8195529","Zeit":"2019-09-27 15:50:07","Artikel":[{"Artikelnummer":"76194","Anzahl":"1","Preis":"2.968"},{"Artikelnummer":"61681","Anzahl":"1","Preis":"7.147"},{"Artikelnummer":"111756","Anzahl":"1","Preis":"9.29"},{"Artikelnummer":"14227","Anzahl":"1","Preis":"0"}]}
```

Code:

```
private static String dirPath = "https://hauteuchdrum.informatik.uni-siegen.de/propra/aufgaben/ws1920/index.php";
         public ArrayList<String> Bestellung(){
            File file = new File (dirPath + "//array_complex.json");
            ArrayList <String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                String str = "{ \"Bestellnummer\": [1,2,3,4,5] }";

                // holt alle 47550 bestellungen vom json  
                for (int i=1; i<2;i++) {
                String POST_PARAMS = "json={\"bid\":\"bid\", \"getorder\":\""+i+"\"}";
                    //System.out.println(POST_PARAMS);

                JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(POST_PARAMS);
                JSONArray arr=obj1.getJSONArray("Bestellnummer");
                for (int z=0; z<arr.length();z++) {
                    String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(z).getString("Bestellnummer");
                    System.out.println(post_id);
                }
                 URL obj = new URL("https://hauteuchdrum.informatik.uni-siegen.de/propra/aufgaben/ws1920/index.php");
                 HttpURLConnection postConnection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                 postConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                 postConnection.setRequestProperty("connection", "Keep-Alive");
                 postConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                 java.io.OutputStream os = postConnection.getOutputStream();
                    os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
                    os.flush();
                    os.close();

                    int responseCode = postConnection.getResponseCode();
                    //System.out.println("POST Response Code :  " + responseCode);
                   // System.out.println("POST Response Message : " + postConnection.getResponseMessage());
                    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(postConnection.getInputStream()));
                        String inputLine;
                        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            response.append(inputLine);
                        } 
                        in.close();
                        // print result
                      //  System.out.println(response.toString());
                        test.add(response.toString());
                     //   java.util.Iterator<String> it = test.iterator();
                     // while (it.hasNext()) {
                       //   System.out.println(it.next());
                    //    }

                    }
        }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            return test;
        }
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is to insert the HTTP response string into database, I strongly recommend you to deserialize the string to POJOs as follows:

Declare 2 classes - `MyResponse` and `Artikel`. `Artikel` is for storing the content of JOSN object in JSON array, and I use `List<Artikel>` for the JSON array. BTW, I also use `@JsonProperty`(provided in Jackson) to map JSON keys with uppercase to variables with lowercase.

```
class MyResponse {
    @JsonProperty(value="Bestellnummer")
    private String bestellnummer;
    @JsonProperty(value="Besteller")
    private String besteller;
    @JsonProperty(value="Zeit")
    private String zeit;
    @JsonProperty(value="Artikel")
    private List<Artikel> artikel;

    //general getters and setters
}

class Artikel {
    @JsonProperty(value="Artikelnummer")
    private String artikelnummer;
    @JsonProperty(value="Anzahl")
    private String anzahl;
    @JsonProperty(value="Preis")
    private String preis;

    //general getters and setters
}
```

Now, you can use Jackson (one of the most popular JSON libraries) to deserialize the HTTP response to our POJOs. And you can manipulate these POJOs for DB operation easily.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyResponse myResponse = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), MyResponse.class);
myResponse.getArtikel().forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Console output**

> Artikel [artikelnummer=76194, anzahl=1, preis=2.968]
>   Artikel [artikelnummer=61681, anzahl=1, preis=7.147]
>   Artikel [artikelnummer=111756, anzahl=1, preis=9.29]
>   Artikel [artikelnummer=14227, anzahl=1, preis=0]

Answer (score 0):

Because you provided too less information to come up with a more detailed answer I came up with the following code.

```
JSONObject main = new JSONObject(data);
String orderNumber = main.getString("Bestellnummer"); // Retrieving the order number
String orderUserId = main.getString("Besteller"); // Retrieving the orderUserId
String time = main.getString("Zeit"); // Retrieving the current time

JSONArray articles = main.getJSONArray("Artikel"); // Getting articles as JSON Array
for (int i = 0; i < articles.length(); i++) { // Looping tough the articles
    JSONObject article = articles.getJSONObject(i); // Getting the article JSON Object
    String articleNumber = article.getString("Artikelnummer"); // Retrieving the Article number
    String amount = article.getString("Anzahl"); // Retrieving the amount
    String price = article.getString("Pris"); // Retrieving the price

    // Your code...
}
```

I hope this helps you.